# How to create a smile animation in Mathematica?

Tags: manipulate, animation, cdf-format

I want to create a yellow smile, with normal mouth which smiles in cycle.
I only know that I need to use CDF player and Manipulate, but do not have any idea how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: With or without teeth?

Comment: It would be great to have teeth :) But actually I'd like to learn how to do both.

Comment: Okay, so a `Yellow` `Disk[]`, two `Point[]`s with the appropriate `PointSize[]` set, and then use a `ParametricPlot[]` to make a transitioning set of circle arcs…

Comment: A better idea for a simple smile: use a symmetric Bézier curve, and just shift the central control points vertically…

Comment: @J.M. Without teeth: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SmileyChanger/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one without teeth, but it does have eyebrows, the eyes can change size, and the mouth smiles (or not):

```
Manipulate[
 eyeMat = {{1/(eyeRadius - pupilRadius/2), 0}, {0, 
    1/(0.15 + eyes - pupilRadius/2)}}; 
 If[Norm[eyeMat.(pup - eyeCenter[[left]])] < 1, 
  pupNow = pup - eyeCenter[[left]];]; 
 If[Norm[eyeMat.(pup - eyeCenter[[right]])] < 1, 
  pupNow = pup - eyeCenter[[right]];]; 
 Graphics[{face, eye[left, eyes], eye[right, eyes], Blue, 
   pupil[left, pupNow, eyes], pupil[right, pupNow, eyes], Black, 
   browDraw[left, brows, eyes], browDraw[right, brows, eyes], 
   Inset[mouthDraw[mouth], {0, -0.5}]}, ImageSize -> {400, 450}],
 {{brows, {-Pi/20, 0}}, {-0.6, 0}, {0.6, 0.15}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left},
 {{eyes, 0}, -0.07, 0.07, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  ControlType -> VerticalSlider},
 {{mouth, 0.15}, -0.401, 0.4, 0.01, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  ControlType -> VerticalSlider},
 {{pup, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, 
 Initialization :> (face = Circle[{0, 0}, {1, 1.2}]; pupNow = {0, 0}; 
   left = 1; right = 2;
   eyeRadius = 0.18; eyeCenter = {{-0.4, 0.15}, {0.4, 0.15}}; 
   pupilRadius = 0.09;
   browUp = 0.25; browW = 0.2; browAng = Pi/20;
   eye[side_, eccen_] := {Black, 
     Circle[eyeCenter[[side]], {eyeRadius + 0.05, eyeRadius + eccen}]};
   pupil[side_, pup_, 
     eccen_] := {Disk[eyeCenter[[side]] + pup + {0, pup[[2]] eccen}, 
      pupilRadius + Max[0, eccen/3]], Black, 
     Disk[eyeCenter[[side]] + pup + {0, pup[[2]] eccen}, 0.03]};
   browDraw[side_, {browAng_, browLift_}, eccen_] := 
    Rotate[{Thickness[0.01], 
      Line[{{eyeCenter[[side]] + {-browW, 
           browLift + browUp + 0.5 eccen}, 
         eyeCenter[[side]] + {browW, 
           browLift + browUp + 0.5 eccen}}}]}, 2 (side - 1.5) browAng];
   mouthDraw[s_] := 
    ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], -s Sin[u]}, {u, Pi/6, Pi - Pi/6}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}, 
     PlotRange -> All];)]
```

[image]

As suggested by "Guess who it is", you can make the face yellow by changing the first line of the Initialization to

```
face = {Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1.2}]};
```